# 削除された投稿の赤い背景がサイドバー側にはみ出てしまう

Tags: バグ, デザイン

### 不具合事象

削除された質問の赤い背景が、画面左側に表示されるサイドバー側にはみ出てしまう場合があります。問題が再現した際のスクリーンショットを以下に示します。

これは下記の再現環境で述べた環境において、画面サイズを800pxにしたときの画像です。はみ出していることが分かりやすいよう、サイドバーの質問、セーブおよびユーザの3つのリンクをホバー状態にしています。

[image: サイドバーと削除された質問が写っているスクリーンショット。削除された質問の赤い背景がサイドバーにはみ出している様子がわかる。]

### 再現環境

- OS：Windows 10 64-bit
- ブラウザ：Opera One(バージョン: 104.0.4944.36)

Comment: はみ出るのは該当の要素に対して margin-left にマイナス値が設定されているから、画面サイズを小さくした時 = レスポンシブデザインでモバイル表示になった時で、スマホで見ても左にズレて表示されますね。日本語版に限らず、ネットワーク全体で再現します。